# Formatting XML file to read in terminal

Tags: android, xml, termux, yq

I'm trying to read a XML file as a text in termux terminal (just like cat). The XML file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<book name="2ª João" abbrev="2jo" chapters="1">

  <chapter number="1">

    <verse number="1">O presbítero à senhora eleita e aos seus filhos, a quem amo na verdade, — e não apenas eu os amo, mas também todos os que conhecem a verdade —</verse>

    <verse number="2">por causa da verdade que permanece em nós e estará conosco para sempre.</verse>

    <verse number="3">A graça, a misericórdia e a paz da parte de Deus Pai e de Jesus Cristo, seu Filho, estarão conosco em verdade e em amor.</verse>
```

There's books, chapters and verses.
I want to print a whole chapter at once.

I'm using mikefarah/yq implementation

So I run:
`yq  -p xml '.book.chapter' < nvi-2jo.xml`

Which returns:

```
+@number: "1"

verse:

  - +content: O presbítero à senhora eleita e aos seus filhos, a quem amo na verdade, — e não apenas eu os amo, mas também todos os que conhecem a verdade —

    +@number: "1"

  - +content: por causa da verdade que permanece em nós e estará conosco para sempre.

    +@number: "2"

  - +content: A graça, a misericórdia e a paz da parte de Deus Pai e de Jesus Cristo, seu Filho, estarão conosco em verdade e em amor.
```

I want to get rid of this "+@number:" and "+content" and print only the text.

Desired output:

'''
O presbítero à senhora eleita e aos seus filhos, a quem amo na verdade, — e não apenas eu os amo, mas também todos os que conhecem a verdade —
por causa da verdade que permanece em nós e estará conosco para sempre.
A graça, a misericórdia e a paz da parte de Deus Pai e de Jesus Cristo, seu Filho, estarão conosco em verdade e em amor.
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The levels of your XML are `book` -> `chapter` -> `verse`. With `.book.chapter` you only go down to `chapter`. Go further into `.verse`, and iterate over its items with `[]`. These items contain a `number` attribute and a text node as content. You get both, type-marked, as fields of a map. If you only want the text nodes, descend once more, into `+content`:

```bash
yq -p xml '.book.chapter.verse[].+content' < nvi-2jo.xml
```

```
O presbítero à senhora eleita e aos seus filhos, a quem amo na verdade, — e não apenas eu os amo, mas também todos os que conhecem a verdade —
por causa da verdade que permanece em nós e estará conosco para sempre.
A graça, a misericórdia e a paz da parte de Deus Pai e de Jesus Cristo, seu Filho, estarão conosco em verdade e em amor.
```